# Why do we need to use grunt - useminPrepare

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, grunt-usemin

I'm a bit confused of why the yeoman angular generator has the concat tasks inside the useminPrepare task since the concat and uglify are run later in the build task.

```
// Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
// concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
// additional tasks can operate on them
useminPrepare: {
  html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
  options: {
    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
    flow: {
      html: {
        steps: {
          js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
          css: ['cssmin']
        },
        post: {}
      }
    }
  }
},



  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'bowerInstall',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
    'ngmin',
    'copy:dist',
    'cdnify',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'rev',
    'usemin',
    'htmlmin'
  ]);
```

can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `useminPrepare` task does not actually do any minification, but instead it parses HTML and sets the appopriate configuration for other tasks. For example, if you have this in your HTML:

```
<!-- build:js js/app.js -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/thing-controller.js"></script>
<script src="js/models/thing-model.js"></script>
<script src="js/views/thing-view.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

The `useminPrepare` task will set the following configuration:

```
{
  concat: {
    '.tmp/concat/js/app.js': [
      'app/js/app.js',
      'app/js/controllers/thing-controller.js',
      'app/js/models/thing-model.js',
      'app/js/views/thing-view.js'
    ]
  },
  uglifyjs: {
    'dist/js/app.js': ['.tmp/concat/js/app.js']
  }
}
```

And the block in the HTML will then be replaced with with:

```
<script src="dist/js/app.js"></script>
```

For more information, see https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin.

Comment: cool, does the concat task in the **build task** then reference that auto generated concat config then?